# undefined children on react parent. However when console.log state is ldefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to load a component using useEffect hook and axios. However, when loading the page the components are not render, but when inspecting the parent component, his children are undefined (I'm very new to react)

**Component**

```
export const BonusRows = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");

  const bonusRequest = () => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/process/creator/gutierad5`)
      .then((res) => {
        const bonus = res.data;
        const processes = bonus.processes;
        setState(processes);
        console.log(processes);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    bonusRequest();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ProcessTable
      funcionality={() => {
        sortByDate(state, setState, order, setOrder);
      }}
    >
      <Accordion allowToggle allowMultiple>
        {state.map((element, index) => {
          <AccordionItemSlot
            key={index}
            proccessID={element.id}
            title={element.name}
            targeruser='gutierad5'
            createDate={FormatDateInYYMMDD(element.createdAt)}
            status={element.status}
            creator={element.creator}
            links={element.links}
            amount={element.processBonus.amount}
            updatedAt={element.updatedAt}
            password={element.processBonus.password}
            franchise={element.processBonus.franchise}
          />;
        })}
      </Accordion>
    </ProcessTable>
  );
};
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My best guess is that the state is not present when the component is loaded, so thet's the reasong is undefined. However when console log the state, the data is there.

Comment: You have no `return` statement in your map function, and you're not using the arrow function shorthand which would make the `return` implicit

Comment: Thanks! that works! I don't know how I missed that.